How to code an indicator in pine which gives an alert when the current day High/Low breaks?
I am looking to code an indicator which shoots an alert when the price makes a new day high or a new day low for the current day.
Most of the codes I have tried are having trouble giving the alerts, either the conditions not met for some reason or have repaint issues.
